# Overloading the constructor of class Thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, constructor, overloading, runnable

I recently started learning Java, and am now using it's my language of choice in my Concurrent Programming class at uni.

I've been working on a lab assignment that requires me to start a few threads and run them in a specific order . Here's the code :

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;


class Lab1{

public static void main(String[] args){

    CountDownLatch leftLatch = new CountDownLatch(3);
    CountDownLatch midLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    LabThread t1 = new LabThread();
    new Thread(t1).start();

    // (new Thread(new LabThread(new CountDownLatch(1),leftLatch,1))).start();
    // (new Thread(new LabThread(new CountDownLatch(0),leftLatch,2))).start();
    // (new Thread(new LabThread(new CountDownLatch(0),leftLatch,3))).start();
    // (new Thread(new LabThread(leftLatch,midLatch,4))).start();
 //     (new Thread(new LabThread(midLatch,new CountDownLatch(0),5))).start();
    // (new Thread(new LabThread(midLatch,new CountDownLatch(0),6))).start();
    // (new Thread(new LabThread(midLatch,new CountDownLatch(0),7))).start();
}
}

public class LabThread implements Runnable{

CountDownLatch waitLatch = null;
CountDownLatch decLatch = null;
int threadNr;

public LabThread(CountDownLatch waitLatch, CountDownLatch decLatch,int threadNr){
    this.waitLatch = waitLatch;
    this.decLatch = decLatch;
    this.threadNr = threadNr;
}

public void run(){
    try{
        this.waitLatch.await();
        this.decLatch.countDown();
    }catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(threadNr);
}
}
```

When I try to compile, I get this error :

```
Lab1.java:12: error: constructor Thread in class Thread cannot be applied to given types;
    new Thread(t1).start();
    ^
required: CountDownLatch,CountDownLatch,int
found: LabThread
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

I know it's pretty self-explanatory, but I just haven't been able to find a workaround .
I tried lots of stuff : getting rid of the overloaded constructor, extending Thread instead of implementing Runnable, anything I thought could help , but it just keeps bugging me with this same error and it's just getting really absurd. If you know a solution,p lease share your wisdom with me on this one !

P.S : I know my logic may be a bit flawed, but I'll get on that after it compiles :)

**EDIT :**
**PROBLEM SOLVED** !
Apparently all I needed to do was clean up my project(delete the class files) and compile again . Many thanks to  Tom Hawtin - tackline and fazomisiek for suggesting I do that .
I did not realize leaving the old files had any effect when compiling anew. My bad ! :)
Thank you everyone for your suggestions, did not expect to get an answer so fast

Comment: Surprised that you didn't get that error for `new LabThread()`

Comment: I'd guess that you originally called `LabThread` `Thread`. Delete all your `.class` files and try again.

Comment: Wow. I deleted all my .class files and it now compiles . Funny how that worked out !
Thanks a lot, Tom ! Would up your comment , but I don't have the needed rep yet:) 
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to bit little messy - thrown exception doesn't fit your code. But, you should use something like this:

```
LabThread t1 = new LabThread(leftLatch, midLatch, 69);
new Thread(t1).start();
```

(But you need to think about logic you want to achive, i.e. how many thread to run, when, etc.)

BTW: Are you sure you are saving your file before compiling? (this error is unexpected)

BTW2: You should call super() in your constructor (you should call constructor of a parent class - this is a good practice).

Comment: Doing it as you suggested above did not help, sadly
Yes, I am saving the file every time before compiling
And I tried calling super() before ,did not help, I thought it might have been the problem. Tried with super() again just now, using your suggestion , same error. Thx though ! :)

Comment: You have some compilation problems - refresh your project, clean project, etc. and try again. Are you using IDE (Eclipse, IntelliJ) ?

Comment: I'm not using any IDEs while learning. Text editor + javac in the terminal ! Cleaning is a great idea, though, as it turned out. Will definetely do it more often :)

Comment: Did it help? :o Ummu if you are using text editor + javac - you should be safe...

Answer (score 0):

Once you define an arguments-constructor, you have to explicitly define a no-argument constructor. The problem with your code is that constructor `LabThread()` does not exist.

You can do one of the following things.

1. Define a no-argument constructor
2. Utilize the defined constructor with the three-arguments.
3. Remove the three-argument constructor.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I didn't notice I was using the no-arg constructor.
I fixed the mistake and it STILL gives me the same error !
I also tried providing a no-arg constructor earlier, didn't help.
still, thx for the suggestion